# TSQL - Only execute a line if run manually (not in job)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can I make an IF statement that only executes when run manually from SSMS?

I have a SQL Server job that executes TSQL code.  That TSQL code is maintained in a separate .sql text file.  When it needs to be edited, I edit the text file and copy&paste the final results into the job.

This normally works very well but there is one critical line that is only used for testing (it sets a variable to a specific value). How can I guarantee that line only executes when run manually?

Is there something like `If ManualExecution() then Blah`?

Comment: Does it *have* to be in the same job step? If not, why not create a new step at position 1 with your test code, but have the schedule  start at step 2 (which is you're current step 1). Then, if you're manually running you start it at step 1, rather than step 2.

Comment: If the Job is running under a different security context (e.g. the SQL Agent's account), you can use CURRENT_USER or a similar function to check if it is running in the desired context. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF APP_NAME() LIKE 'Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio%'
BEGIN
  PRINT 'Running inside SSMS'
END;
```

If you use SQL Agent to run the job, it's app name should be `SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0x... : Step ...)`. If you use some other software, just make sure that it doesn't set its [Application Name](https://www.connectionstrings.com/use-application-name-sql-server/) to "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"...

Comment: I ran a test and the job sees itself as `SQLAgent - TSQL JobStep (Job 0xblahblahblah : Step 1)`. Perfect!

Comment: @PowerUser: Thanks, I wasn't sure and didn't have an SQL Agent ready to test. I have added that information to my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the SQL Server Agent `JobId` of the current process (otherwise `NULL`):

```
declare @JobId as UniqueIdentifier;

begin try
  -- The executed statement will result in a syntax error if not in a SQL Server Agent job.
  execute sp_executesql
    @stmt = N'select @JobId = Cast( $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID)) as UniqueIdentifier );',
    @params = N'@JobId UniqueIdentifier output',
    @JobId = @JobId output;
end try
begin catch
  if @@Error != 102 -- 102 = Syntax error.
    select @@Error; -- Handle unexpected errors here.
end catch

select @JobId as JobId; -- NULL if not running as a SQL Server Agent job.
```

Note that the `JobId` can be used to access additional information about the current job in [`dbo.sysjobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).